# Auto layout constraint + rotation = constraints not updated

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Here is my architecture :

[image]

I don't want to set a specific frame size for the PageViewController so I have set this couple of constraints in the viewDidLoad method :

```
pageView!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let views = ["pageView": pageView!.view]

let constH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[pageView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
view.addConstraints(constH)

let heightConstant = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height + self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.origin.y

let constW = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-\(heightConstant)-[pageView]-\(self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height)-|", options: .AlignAllTrailing, metrics: nil, views: views)
    view.addConstraints(constW)
```

In other words, top padding equals to the navigation bar's height and bottom padding equals to the tabbar's one. This is working great in portrait mode.

The problem is when I rotate my device, the constW is not re-computed and in landscape mode, there is an extra space between the navigation bar and the top of pageNavigation since the change of size of the navigation bar has not been detected.

The only workaround I found is removing the constH constraint in viewDidLayoutSubviews, and adding it back. But I think I have missed something since it doesn't follow the "**auto** layout" concept.

Comment: Do you get any autolayout warnings in the debugger when you rotate?

Comment: I actually don't think you need to compute the size of the navigation bar since you are using a navigation controller. I have a sample project on GitHub using VSL, and it works fine rotating between Landscape and Portrait. Check it out here https://github.com/michaelsabo/VisualFormatLanguageExample

Comment: You should just have "V:|[pageView]-\(self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height)-|" for your vertical constraint

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work, the top of my tableView is behind the navigation bar.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to visualize this but having a bit of trouble with all the pieces. Why is the tableView underneath the navigation bar?

Comment: I was using tableViewController but with a UITableView + delegate/datasource properly set, it works :)